# What is the proper way to disable SwipeRefreshLayout pull to refresh

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I have a ListView that uses a SwipeRefreshLayout. it works. but i don't always want the pull to refresh animation nor callback to trigger.

In my case, the pull to refresh action synchronises the view with a server, but server sync can be optionally disabled as a preference. when the sync is disabled, i don't want pull to referesh to happen at all.

What im currently doing is subclassing SwipeRefreshLayout and overriding `canChildScrollUp' to "lie" when actually it can't but i don't want the animation.

thus:

```
private class ListFragmentSwipeRefreshLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout
{
    public ListFragmentSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context) { super(context); }

    @Override
    public boolean canChildScrollUp()
    {
        final ListView view = getListView();
        if (view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
            return !shouldShowRefresh(view);

        return false;
    }
}
```

where the implementation of `shouldShowRefresh' considers whether it can, in fact, scroll combined with my network sync settings.

This way of doing it is working, but im asking this question because it sounds like a common requirement and conflating `canChildScrollUp' is rather messy.

thanks.

Comment: Why dont you just dont use SwipeRefreshLayout when you dont want and use a normal listview in that case? isnt that so much simple?

Comment: @Nanoc, `setEnabled' does trick as answered below. Your approach would be better only if one or the other were required for the lifetime of the view. as it turns out, i want to change the enablement whilst the view is active.

Answer (score 8):

If I got it right, you want to enable and disable the *SwipeRefreshLayout* considering the state of the sync. You can make something like this

```
if(sync){
  swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
else
  swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
```

where the sync is the boolean value which says if sync is enabled or not.

Comment: thanks. I was under the impression that `setEnabled' related to the enablement of the layout itself and would disable my listview. You are right, this enablement only enables/disables the swipe action. This is the answer thanks.